# Problems with .editorconfig file in VS2017 Community

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I'm using this .editorconfig file for a group project and one of the naming conventions we're using is that private members are supposed to be camelCase prefixed with underscores.

The problem is, for some reason, the rule isn't matching on private members in classes in my project. Any ideas?

```
# top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

# Don't use tabs for indentation.
[*]
indent_style = space

# Code files
[*.{cs,csx}]
indent_size = 4
insert_final_newline = true
charset = utf-8-bom

# Xml project files
[*.csproj]
indent_size = 2

# JSON files
[*.json]
indent_size = 4

# Dotnet code style settings:
[*.cs]

# TRUE

csharp_style_expression_bodied_properties = true:suggestion
csharp_space_after_keywords_in_control_flow_statements = true:suggestion
csharp_preserve_single_line_blocks = true:suggestion

dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_locals_parameters_members = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_predefined_type_for_member_access = true:suggestion

dotnet_style_collection_initializer = true:suggestion
dotnet_style_explicit_tuple_names = true:suggestion

csharp_prefer_simple_default_expression = true:suggestion

csharp_style_throw_expression = true:suggestion

csharp_prefer_braces = true:suggestion

csharp_new_line_before_members_in_object_initializers = true:suggestion
csharp_new_line_before_members_in_anonymous_types = true:suggestion

csharp_indent_case_contents = true:suggestion
csharp_indent_switch_labels = true:suggestion

# FALSE

csharp_style_expression_bodied_constructors = false:suggestion
csharp_style_expression_bodied_operators = false:suggestion
csharp_style_expression_bodied_indexers = false:suggestion
csharp_style_expression_bodied_accessors = false:suggestion

csharp_space_after_cast = false:suggestion

csharp_space_between_method_declaration_parameter_list_parentheses = false:suggestion
csharp_space_between_method_call_parameter_list_parentheses = false:suggestion

csharp_preserve_single_line_statements = false:suggestion

dotnet_style_qualification_for_field = false:suggestion
dotnet_style_qualification_for_property = false:suggestion
dotnet_style_qualification_for_method = false:suggestion
dotnet_style_qualification_for_event = false:suggestion

csharp_style_var_for_built_in_types = false:suggestion
csharp_style_var_when_type_is_apparent = false:suggestion
csharp_style_var_elsewhere = false:suggestion

csharp_style_inlined_variable_declaration = false:suggestion

csharp_style_pattern_local_over_anonymous_function = false:suggestion

csharp_new_line_before_else = false:suggestion
csharp_new_line_before_catch = false:suggestion
csharp_new_line_before_finally = false:suggestion

# PARAMETERS

csharp_space_between_parentheses = NONE
dotnet_style_require_accessibility_modifiers = always
csharp_preferred_modifier_order = public,private,protected,internal,static,extern,new,virtual,abstract,sealed,override,readonly,unsafe,volatile,async

csharp_new_line_before_open_brace = all
csharp_indent_labels = flush_left

# BEGIN NAMING
# Naming Rules
# Private fields must be camelCase prefixed with underscore
dotnet_naming_rule.private_members_with_underscore.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule_private_members_with_underscore.symbols = private_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.private_members_with_underscore.style = underscore_prefix
# Constant fields must be PascalCase
dotnet_naming_rule.constant_fields_must_be_pascal_case.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.constant_fields_must_be_pascal_case.symbols = constant_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.constant_fields_must_be_pascal_case.style = pascal_case
# Public, internal and protected readonly fields must be PascalCase
dotnet_naming_rule.non_private_readonly_fields_must_be_pascal_case.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.non_private_readonly_fields_must_be_pascal_case.symbols = non_private_readonly_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.non_private_readonly_fields_must_be_pascal_case.style = pascal_case
# Static readonly fields must be PascalCase
dotnet_naming_rule.static_readonly_fields_must_be_pascal_case.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.static_readonly_fields_must_be_pascal_case.symbols = static_readonly_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.static_readonly_fields_must_be_pascal_case.style = pascal_case
# Private readonly fields must be camelCase
dotnet_naming_rule.private_readonly_fields_must_be_camel_case.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.private_readonly_fields_must_be_camel_case.symbols = private_readonly_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.private_readonly_fields_must_be_camel_case.style = underscore_prefix
# Public and internal fields must be PascalCase
dotnet_naming_rule.public_internal_fields_must_be_pascal_case.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.public_internal_fields_must_be_pascal_case.symbols = public_internal_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.public_internal_fields_must_be_pascal_case.style = pascal_case
# Public members must be capitalized
dotnet_naming_rule.public_members_must_be_capitalized.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.public_members_must_be_capitalized.symbols = public_symbols
dotnet_naming_rule.public_members_must_be_capitalized.style = first_upper
# Parameters must be camelCase
dotnet_naming_rule.parameters_must_be_camel_case.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.parameters_must_be_camel_case.symbols = parameters
dotnet_naming_rule.parameters_must_be_camel_case.style = camel_case
# Class, struct, enum and delegates must be PascalCase
dotnet_naming_rule.non_interface_types_must_be_pascal_case.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.non_interface_types_must_be_pascal_case.symbols = non_interface_types
dotnet_naming_rule.non_interface_types_must_be_pascal_case.style = pascal_case
# Interfaces must be PascalCase and start with an 'I'
dotnet_naming_rule.interface_types_must_be_prefixed_with_i.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.interface_types_must_be_prefixed_with_i.symbols = interface_types
dotnet_naming_rule.interface_types_must_be_prefixed_with_i.style = prefix_interface_interface_with_i

# Naming Symbols
# constant_fields - Define constant fields
dotnet_naming_symbols.constant_fields.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.constant_fields.required_modifiers = const
# non_private_readonly_fields - Define public, internal and protected readonly fields
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_private_readonly_fields.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, protected
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_private_readonly_fields.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_private_readonly_fields.required_modifiers = readonly
# static_readonly_fields - Define static and readonly fields
dotnet_naming_symbols.static_readonly_fields.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.static_readonly_fields.required_modifiers = static, readonly
# public_internal_fields - Define public and internal fields
dotnet_naming_symbols.public_internal_fields.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal
dotnet_naming_symbols.public_internal_fields.applicable_kinds = field
# private_fields - Define private fields
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_accessibilities = private
# protected_fields - Define protected fields
dotnet_naming_symbols.protected_fields.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.protected_fields.applicable_accessibilities = protected
# public_symbols - Define any public symbol
dotnet_naming_symbols.public_symbols.applicable_accessibilities = public, internal, protected, protected_internal
dotnet_naming_symbols.public_symbols.applicable_kinds = method, property, event, delegate
# parameters - Defines any parameter
dotnet_naming_symbols.parameters.applicable_kinds = parameter
# non_interface_types - Defines class, struct, enum and delegate types
dotnet_naming_symbols.non_interface_types.applicable_kinds = class, struct, enum, delegate
# interface_types - Defines interfaces
dotnet_naming_symbols.interface_types.applicable_kinds = interface
# private_readonly_fields - Define private readonly fields
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_readonly_fields.required_modifiers = readonly
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_readonly_fields.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_readonly_fields.applicable_accessibilities = private

# Naming Styles
# camel_case - Define the camelCase style
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.capitalization = camel_case
# pascal_case - Define the Pascal_case style
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case.capitalization = pascal_case
# first_upper - The first character must start with an upper-case character
dotnet_naming_style.first_upper.capitalization = first_word_upper
# underscore_prefix - The first character must be prefixed with an underscore
dotnet_naming_style.underscore_prefix.capitalization = camel_case
dotnet_naming_style.underscore_prefix.required_prefix = _
# prefix_interface_interface_with_i - Interfaces must be PascalCase and the first character of an interface must be an 'I'
dotnet_naming_style.prefix_interface_interface_with_i.capitalization = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_style.prefix_interface_interface_with_i.required_prefix = I
```

Example:

```
private bool _thisMember;
```

The above should pass just fine, whereas

```
private bool ThisMember;
```

should flag a warning.

Answer (score 1):

In case you still didn't find out the problem, it is a typo on your declaration:

```
dotnet_naming_rule_private_members_with_underscore.symbols = private_fields
```

You put an underscore instead of a dot after "dotnet_naming_rule".

If you change the above line to the below, it should work.

```
dotnet_naming_rule.private_members_with_underscore.symbols = private_fields
```

Comment: I am editing the .editorconfig but the changes are not getting applied. I am unloading the projects of the solution to apply the changes. Is there anything else to be done?